# LED dies under a 3.75V lithium-ion battery, but works fine with a 9V PP3

Tags: led, resistance, lithium-ion

I have a bag of unlabeled LEDs and intend to use them in a project. I connected one to a 9V PP3 to test it out, and was quite surprised to see that it didn't blow, given the fact I hadn't used a resistor.

I figured that they must be rated for 9 or 12 volts.  I then decided to hook one up to a 3.75V Li-ion battery, and it promptly died. Why is this? Do PP3 batteries have some sort of voltage protection, or is it a current thing?

Comment: Maybe visit https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/151627/why-does-an-led-have-a-maximum-voltage Do you want to *test* the LEDs, or do you want to *fry* them?

Comment: Please stop playing around and shorting li-ion cells into LEDs before you hurt yourself or start a fire.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

A fresh alkaline 9V battery can easily fry a lot of smaller LEDs. It can deliver a couple of amperes into a short circuit. A zinc-carbon 9V battery has a considerably higher internal resistance (hence their unsuitability for certain applications) so the LED may well survive (although possibly with damage).

Not-so-fresh cells have higher internal resistance, so even if they measure a similar open-circuit voltage, that does not provide a good indication of what they will do when connected across the hapless LED.

Most Li-ion cells can deliver quite a bit of current (low internal resistance) so it's not surprising the LED did not survive.

At the other end of the spectrum, a CR2025 or CR2032 cell has enough internal resistance (and a lower ~3V voltage) so that most LEDs will survive without damage, so one sometimes sees vendors at electronics markets demonstrating LEDs by connecting them directly across such a cell.

Comment: Those cheap keychain lights also often consist of just CR2032 cells and LEDs. I had one without even a switch - squeezing it in the right place simply made the LED legs touch the cell.

Answer (score 36):

The 9V battery can't source much current into a load or short circuit. Approximately 500mA depending on many things.

Lithium-ion batteries, depending on many things, could potentially source tens of amps into a load or short circuit.

They have different internal resistance.

Answer (score 18):

> given the fact I hadn't used a resistor

You did use a resistor. The relatively high internal resistance of the 9V battery limited the current. Charged Li-ion cells of similar volume have internal resistance lower by a couple orders of magnitude compared to a 9V battery.